# React Native - Random ReferenceErrors (Can't find variable)

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

When running our app I'm seeing some ReferenceErrors. They seem to be on and off because there are builds where the app works fine and in the next build it crashes on a ReferenceError. For example:

```js
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: interpolatedCircleColor
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: _careItem (this comes from a component I created)
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: state
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: style
```

Each build I get one of these errors. It never seems to be missing more than one variable. There are four components where the errors come from. Other screens/components work just fine. These components don't work together in any way. They all just display data passed on as a prop. The errors are now visible in both development and release builds. On development builds the errors are shown, when I fix them everything seems to be OK. But after a release build it needs different variables and the app shows a white screen.

I used to overcome this problem by defining the missing variables as an empty string in the component that needed it. But this is just a hack to get it to work (sometimes). But with some 'variables' it expected a function this is where I decided the problem needed to be fixed for good.

Example. I would pass these variables in the render function of the component:

```js
const interpolatedCircleColor = '';
const interpolatedTranslateX = '';
const handlerAnimation = '';
const height = '';
const style = '';
const state = '';
const opacityStyle = '';
const substitutionStyle = '';
const containerStyles = '';
const tintColor = '';
```

I suspect the problem is with bundling the app as this is where I can find the missing variables.

To build the app in release mode I use the following process:

1. `rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && watchman watch-del-all && yarn cache clean`
2. `cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ..`
3. `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res --sourcemap-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle.map`
4. `npx react-native run-android --variant=release`

This would then give me one of the errors I mentioned above. In one of the four components.

Additional information:

```
"react-native": "0.63.1",
"react": "16.13.1",
```

```
node v14.5.0
npm 6.14.5
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!